# How to reference CSV alongside GeoJSON for D3 rollover

Tags: csv, d3.js, geojson

I'm trying to make a rollover map in D3 that allows me to use a standard world GeoJSON file and a CSV that matches up with ISO ids. I'm able to match everything when it comes to highlighting the countries and coloring them differently, but I can't seem to reference the values when it comes to populating a text field. Here a selection from my code:

```
    function setUpChoropleth(error, json, _csv) {
      csv = _csv;

      svg.append("g")
      .selectAll("path")
        .data(topojson.feature(json, json.objects.countries).features)
      .enter().append("svg:path")
        .attr("d", path)
          .on("mouseover", function(d,i) {
            var mouse = d3.mouse(svg.node()).map( function(d) { return parseInt(d); } );
            d3.select("#map1 h2 span").text(d);
          });

      states2.selectAll("path")
          .data(topojson.feature(json, json.objects.countries).features)
        .enter().append("svg:path")
          .attr("d", path)
          .attr("class", function(d,i) { return "country" + d.id; });
      states3.selectAll("path")
          .data(topojson.feature(json, json.objects.countries).features)
        .enter().append("svg:path")
          .attr("d", path)
          .attr("class", function(d,i) { return "country" + d.id; });

    } 

    function drawTierI() {
      csv.forEach(function(d) { tierById.set(d.id, +d.tier_i); });

      function ready(error, json, _csv) {
        svg.selectAll("path")
            .attr("class", function(d) { return quantize(tierById.get(d.id)); })
            .attr("d", path)
            .on("mouseover", function(d) {
              d3.select("#map1 .panel h3").text(d.id);
            });
      }
      ready();
    }

    $('button#tier_i').click(function (e) {
      drawTierI();
      d3.select("#map1 .panel-title").text("Countries equipped with drones")
      d3.select("#map1 .panel-body").text("These countries are equipped with drones.")
    });
```

I also have a demo here: http://newamericafoundation.github.io/worldofdrones/map.html

When you click on the "Has drones" link and rollover the countries, the only variables I have access to are the variables in the GeoJSON. Is it possible to use the same join I used to highlight the CSV data on the map to bring in data from that same spreasheet, wod.csv?

Please help me, even a clue would help!

Thanks!

Comment: You can merge the CSV into the TopoJSON, see http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5562380

Comment: Is there a way to do this without merging the data with TopoJSON? The hope is I can update this data repeatedly, which is easier to do editing a separate CSV rather than having one of our staffers run TopoJSON on the command line.

Comment: Of course, but then you have to do the matching by hand. That is, on mouseover get the ID and iterate through your CSV data until you've found this ID.

Comment: That makes sense. Any place I should go to start figuring out how to do that? I'm assuming I need a Javascript for loop, right? I pieced this together from disparate mbostock examples and some help here, so I keep hitting a wall on this one issue.

Comment: You could also iterate through the geojson and add an attribute matching by id's.

Comment: I'm willing to try either approach. Here is where I'm headed and I feel pretty stuck:

        .on("mouseover", function(d) {
          for (var i=0;i<csv.length;i++) {
            if (csv[i]['id'] = d.id) {
              // Not sure what to do here
            }
          }
        });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both Lar's and my idea involve iterating through the data and matching ids.  Lars would do this on the fly, so whenever you hovered over an element the relevant text would pop up in the reporting tab.  In mine on the the other hand you pre processes the data just after it's loaded so the csv data is joined to the geojson data.  This might save you a lot of time depending on how much data you have as the join is only done once.

The data joining occurs in a function like this:

```
    csv.forEach(function(d, i) {
        geojson.forEach(function(e, j) {
            if (d.id === e.id) {
                e.name = d.name
            }
        })
    })
```

This code expects that there is a column in the csv that has a list of id's that match some property in the json file which I have assumed is also called id.  The code has two loops, the outer loop is for the csv data and the inner loop is for the geojson data.  The outer loop selects the first id value in the csv and then checks against the id values in the json and when it finds one that matches it creates a new variable in the json called name and adds the corresponding name value from the csv file.

And you can see it in action [here](http://bl.ocks.org/phil-pedruco/10447085)

Comment: Thanks so much! I tried this but still came up short. There also seems to be a name field in your JSON already and there is none in my example, is that the difference? I'm also using a different json and CSV file and I use topojson to draw my map. Here's my code that follows your example:

http://newamericafoundation.github.io/worldofdrones/map.html

Comment: I thought you were using goejson! Not to worry you have to unpack topojson to geojson anyway so the code in my bl.ock will only require a few additional changes.  I've had a look at your map and when I inspected that topojson data I couldn't see any properties in the objects which means there is nothing to match against in the json data in the loops in the code above. When you convert to topojson it does not include properties by default and you have to use the -p switch. I've discsussed this a bit in this [bl.ock](http://bl.ocks.org/phil-pedruco/9999984) the SO question it answers.

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH! I've finally figured this out. I switched to geojson and changed the loop just a bit and BOOM, the map is working as hoped. Here is my complete demo with code here:

https://newamericafoundation.github.io/worldofdrones/map.html